# How to run a Pyinstaller compiled exe with NSSM

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, nssm

I used Pyinstaller to make a exe. The exe works perfectly fine but when I use NSSM to launch it on startup, the scripts runs but does nothing from the part where it is supposed to take an input from user. I also tried moving that part of code to a new python file and call that py file from the compiled exe but it isn't working as well. What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

this is about nssm Environment variables issue

1. nssm edit servicename
2. select Environment
3. Enviroment variables  , KEY=Vaule

Comment: nssm service editor  select I/O, configure Output and error  log。